# Duration of shield

Tags: clash-of-clans

I was attacked and the destruction was 100%, but I got a <s>shield</s> guard for 30 mins. After the <s>shield</s> guard ended I was attacked again and got a <s>shield</s> guard for 30 mins for 100% destruction. And then again after 30 mins I was attacked and then I got a shield for 16 hours. I know the shield duration is 12 hours when 30% destruction and so on. What I am wondering is why didn't I get the shield for those two attacks on me.

Comment: Have you attacked while having the shield? The duration of the shield after a 90%+ destruction should always be 16 hours, as seen on the Clash of clans [wiki](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Shields)

Comment: Of course I didn't attack at all during the sheild of these attacks.. but yeah before these 3 attacks on me.. I had a 16 hour sheild but i attacked while I had that sheild and that sheild was off..

Comment: Then it may be some kind of a bug... Otherwise, I don't know the answer for this.

Comment: And yeah this wasn't the first time I didn't get a full sheild.. all this on my th6 account while on th8 there's always a proper duration for sheild when I am attacked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://forum.supercell.com/showthread.php/918490-From-the-Dev-s-Desk-Shields-Part-I-Attacking-and-Defending

Attacks of less than a 1/3rd maximum army capacity (based on the Army Camp, Spells and Hero capacity of the defender's Town Hall level) will not grant any shield.

Answer (score 0):

The Shield is granted immedeatly after the attack, not when you log in. So, you were attacked 15 hours and 30 minutes before you logged in.
The Shield applies after any attack that damaged 30% or more of the base, no matter the amount of troops deployed. *The 1/3 Troops deployed rule only applies for Guard, which is given after an attack that damaged your base less than 30%.*

Comment: Nope.. I immediately logged in after attack and I had a 30 min guard and no shield.. The destruction was 100%.. And i have confirmed with other clanmates that this has happened to them too..

Comment: Please edit your question and change "30 min Shield" to "30 min Guard". @MehravishTemkar